# JavaScript to C# UTF-8 encoding issue

Tags: c#, javascript, encoding, request, decoding

I have an issue with encoding between JavaScript and C#. I'm creating an url in JavaScript like this:

```
window.location.href = 'url/home/projects/ProjectName/Schockville-Attert - Rue des Blés';
```

Internally this URL is rewritten to the following:

```
'url/home/projects/ProjectNameSchockville-Attert%20-%20Rue%20des%20Bl%C3%A9s'
```

That is the encoded url and that is correct.

Now I want to get the parameter out of the url with C#'s Request like the following:

```
Request["ProjectName"]
```

But ProjectName returns me:

```
Schockville-Attert - Rue des BlÃ©s
```

When I look into my Request property I see that my %C3%A9 has become %u00c3 %u00a9. I search the internet and found out that it is a encoding issue. This is latin format and it has to be UTF-8 format.

I already tried:
[encodeURIComponent, trouble with ü,ç,İ,ı,ğ,ö](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405001/encodeuricomponent-trouble-with-u-c-i-g-o)

I triend unescaping my string but this won't work either. Tried to encode my string to UTF-8 and didn't work.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You do want to be using `encodeURIComponent` when setting the `href` rather than relying on it happening "automatically", e.g., `window.location.href = 'url/home/projects/ProjectName/' + encodeURIComponent('Schockville-Attert - Rue des Blés');` But I suspect that's only part of the problem.

Comment: I've already tried that but that gives me the encoded URI like I showed above and still the same problem on decoding the URI in C#

Comment: @ Jurgen: As I said, I don't think it's the solution, it's just part of it. I wouldn't rely on that encoding being correctly done automatically. But the underlying problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

The string is coming in as **Encoding.Default**, try the code below:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(myString);
myString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```